# What file from Next build do I serve statically with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

When I use React, all I have to do is run npm build, copy the content to a folder called `public` in Node, and then I add the following lines, and it will work:

node/app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//...routes

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})
```

Everything works, the content from all links are shown as they should, and it's fine.

However, running `npm run build` in NextJS produces a index.html file inside `.../server/pages`.

So I did this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//... routes


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'server', 'pages', 'index.html'))
})
```

Running the node app does shows the `index.htm` file content, but clicking any link in it will just redirect to index.html page, even though the displayed url changes.

Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serve it as a React application, you need to use  [Static HTML Export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export), which would generate a build folder like React by running `next build && next export`. Doing so would work, but you won't get all Next.js features such as: `Image Optimization`, `Internationalized Routing`, `API Routes`, `Headers`, `Middleware`, `getServerSideProps`.

That's because Next.js  is designed to be a Node.js / React "Full Stack" framework. Hence the recommended way is to use it as a standalone application with `npm run build && next start`.